# Sweetalert - validation isn't working + form is not submitting

Tags: javascript, forms, sweetalert2

I am trying to implement [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) but for some reason it doesn't apply regular html validation (i.e. required='true' isn't working),
I am not getting an error that the field is empty.

Without swall2, it does prompt me with an error that the field is blank.

Also, once I confirm, in the swall dialog, that I want to proceed ("Yes, submit it!"), it does not submit the form.

What am I missing?

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5hd8wmp/1/)

HTML:

```
<form>
   <label>Last Name</label>
   <input type="text"  required="true"/>
   <input class="btnn" type="submit" name="submit" id="btn-submit"/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#btn-submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('form');
    swal.fire({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, submit it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) form.submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says after it has migrated to sweetalert2 the structure has changed from callback approach

```
swal(
      {title: 'Are you sure?', showCancelButton: true}, function(isConfirm) {
      if (isConfirm) {
      // handle confirm
      } else {
      // handle all other cases
    }
  }
)
```

to promise based approach

```
Swal.fire({title: 'Are you sure?', showCancelButton: true}).then(result => {
 if (result.value) {
  // handle Confirm button click
 // result.value will contain `true` or the input value
 } else {
   // handle dismissals
   // result.dismiss can be 'cancel', 'overlay', 'esc' or 'timer'
 }
})
```

Comment: I am still able to get to the sweetalert2 dialog box even if the field remains blank.

Comment: You should check the form validation by javascript itself if you override the default submit behaviour. For more information see this link. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-algorithm

Comment: you are right, I managed to get the validation going. However, I added this part                         if (result.value) {
  form.submit();
}
But then I'm stuck in a loop, every time I hit Confirm it prompts me with the swal2 dialog and does not proceed to submit the form - any thoughts?

Comment: wrap it around a conditional block, i.e only pass through if the validation succeeds else just return false.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like that.

```
                $('#btn-submit').on('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $('form');
                console.log("hello");
                swal.fire({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes, submit it!",
                }).then(function (result){
                    if(result.value === true){
                    console.log("Submitted");
                    form.submit();
                  }
                });
            });
```

For more information you can look examples about SweetAlert2 from https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples

Answer (score 0):

You can call swal on submit of form, currently on clicking on submit button swal confirm box called before form submit.
JSFiddle Link : [sweetalert](https://jsfiddle.net/bmvgcx5y/)
Try below code :

```js
                $('#form1').on('submit',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var form = $('form');
                    swal.fire({
                        title: "Are you sure?",
                        type: "warning",
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                        confirmButtonText: "Yes, submit it!",
                        closeOnConfirm: false
                    }, function(isConfirm){
                      
                        if (isConfirm) form.submit();
                    });
                });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
<label for="">Last Name</label><span class="required">  *</span>
<input type="text"  required />
<input class="btnn" type="submit" name="submit" id="btn-submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```